# MYSql query with inner joins returns duplicate results

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am trying to get the posts by the users that the userID (`?` in the query) follows, AND get the posts by `?` user, themselves.

```
SELECT 
    posts.id AS postid, posts.user AS user, posts.images AS images, posts.post_created, posts.textvalue, posts.textpost,
    users.username AS authorname
FROM posts
INNER JOIN follows ON (posts.user = follows.follows AND follows.user = ?) OR posts.user = ?
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user
ORDER BY posts.post_created DESC LIMIT 20
```

This query works, but for every post that is by `?` it returns the row twice, when I remove `OR posts.user = ?` it works fine, but does not show the posts for the `?` user id.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Make it select * instead and you'll see why. Right now you only select some columns, and if the data that is causing the unexpected doubling is not selected then you don't see it, you just see the duplicated data. If you select * then analyse every column you'll see that some columns in a pair of "duplicate rows" are different. Work out which row to keep and specify what it is about that row in order to form a where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT p.*, u.username AS authorname
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = p.user LEFT JOIN
     follows f
     ON p.user = f.follows AND f.user = ?
WHERE f.user IS NOT NULL OR  -- a match on the "follows" condition
      p.user = ?             -- a match on the post condition   
ORDER BY p.post_created DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Your query is a but confusing.  But basically you have this condition for posts from the user:

```
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     follows f
     ON p.user = ?
```

(forget the `OR` part -- that only further increases the number of rows.)

There is no `JOIN` condition between the two tables, so you are getting a row for every user that follows the post.